Issue Removing User from Teams Call Using Graph API in Postman: "Application is not registered in our store" Error
I've been trying to remove a user from a Teams call using Postman and Graph API, but I keep getting this error:
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"7503\",\"message\":\"Application is not registered in our store.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2024-07-22T17:30:23",
        "request-id": "6b3721f6-f1f4-4d95-b953-a443bfd023f7",
        "client-request-id": "6b3721f6-f1f4-4d95-b953-a443bfd023f7"
    }
}

}
The service I'm calling is:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/g35Yz6xDyUCkF90GCQgfDA.1/participants/cc0d36a3-8b6e-468f-868b-7a151ff3463b
I authenticated with an app registration to which I've assigned the following permissions 
For testing, I am using my Microsoft 365 developer instant sandbox.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

We will look into it and get back to you.

Could you please try by generating an access token without user as mentioned [Get access without a user][https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service] and passed it in the authorization.

Hello Sayali, Thank you for your suggestion.
The access is already being performed using a client ID, secret, and bearer token. The permissions highlighted are those granted to the client ID used to request the token.

The error message you're seeing indicates that the application you are trying to use is not recognized or registered in the Microsoft store, which typically refers to Azure AD's app registrations. This issue commonly arises due to misconfigurations or missing permissions.

Here are some  steps toresolve this issue:

Check Application Registration in Azure AD 2. Verify API Permissions 3. Access Token and Authorization 4. Retry the Request

